# FirebaseFirestore.instance.collectionGroup('some'),subCollection is displaying same duplicated data for Nth user even though other user didnt upload

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I'm using StreamBuilder to fetch data from cloud Firestore subcollection. It's working, but it's duplicating data for every user in the database, like user(mario) posted his pic and other user(bowser) posted his pic but in emulator it's showing mario's pic for both mario and bowser as if they both uploaded the same pic.

I have attached screenshots to clear my question as I couldn't ask clearly. Is this happening because of the `collectionGroup` statement or is it a logic error? And, how do I solve this problem?

[image: bowser]
[image: mario]

Here is the pic of database:

[image: database]

[image: database]
[image: database]
[image: database]

Below is my code.

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.black,
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigation(),
      appBar: AppBar(
        automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
        backgroundColor: Colors.black,
        title: Text(
          "Platform",
          style: TextStyle(
            color: Colors.white,
            fontSize: 32.6,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
            fontFamily: "Yaldevi",
          )
        )
      ),
      body: StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
        stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collectionGroup('posts').snapshots(),
        builder:(context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot){
          final List<DocumentSnapshot> document = snapshot.data!.docs;
          return ListView(
            children: document.map((doc) => Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                SingleChildScrollView(
                  child: StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
                    stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collectionGroup('usersData').snapshots(),
                    builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot){
                      final List<DocumentSnapshot> data = snapshot.data!.docs;
                      return Column(
                        children: data.map((docs) => Column(
                          children: [
                            ListTile(
                                leading: docs['profileImage'] == null ?
                                CircleAvatar(
                                  radius: 16.6,
                                  backgroundColor: Colors.white24,
                                ) :
                                CircleAvatar(
                                  radius: 16.6,
                                  backgroundImage: NetworkImage(
                                    docs['profileImage'],
                                  ),
                                ),
                              title: Text(
                                docs['displayName'],
                                style: TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                )
                              ),
                              subtitle: doc['title'] != null ?
                                  Text(
                                    doc['title'],
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                      color: Colors.white,
                                    )
                                  ) :
                                  Text(
                                    "PUTA"
                                  )
                            ),
                            Container(
                              height: 400,
                              width: 400,
                              decoration: doc['photoURL'] != null ?
                                  BoxDecoration(
                                    image: DecorationImage(
                                      image: NetworkImage(
                                        doc['photoURL'],
                                      ),
                                      fit: BoxFit.contain,
                                    )
                                  ) :
                                  BoxDecoration(
                                    color: Colors.white24,
                                  )
                            )
                          ]

                        )).toList(),
                      );
                    }
                  ),
                )

              ],
            )).toList(),
          );
        }
      )
    );
```

Comment: Hard to see the picture of your Firebase... Is it possible you have another sub-collection somewhere else with the same data? remember that you are using `collectionGroup('posts')` not `collection('posts')`

Comment: re-uploaded pictures!!

Comment: solved it had to create a whole different data structure and didn`t need to use nested StreamBuilder